# Convert an IEnumerable to a selectlistItem for a dropdownbox

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have this method that generates 3 dates. I want to be able to use the dates in 
a dropdown. I need it to return a selectlistItem. How can I convert this?

```
        public static IEnumerable<MyDates> GenerateLastThreeDates()
        {
            IEnumerable<MyDates> rangeList = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }.Select(n => DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(n))) // Transforming the integer (kind of index of days) array into dates.
                .Where(n => n.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday).Take(3) // Removing the Sunday and taking 3 days only.
                .Select(n => new MyDates() { Dateseries = n }); // Converting the date in your MyDates structure.
            return rangeList.ToList();
        }
```

I tried this but no luck.

```
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> myCollection = GenerateLastThreeDates
                                           .Select(i => new SelectListItem()
                                                        {
                                                            Text = i.ToString(), 
                                                            Value = i
                                                        });


        public class MyDates
        {
            public DateTime Dateseries { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate the dates in your controller
2. Convert the dates into `SelectListItem` instances
3. Store the list in your `ViewData` - which is how you pass non-model (i.e. unidirectional data, not bidirectional data) to a view from the controller
4. Render the list using the ViewData:

For example:

#### Controller

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    private static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GenerateLastThreeDates()
    {
        // note that your code should be timezone-aware, so consider using DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime
        // also, never reference DateTime.Today (or Now, or UtcNow) in a loop - because the value can change in successive calls, instead you should store the value and re-use the cached copy
        DateTime now = DateTime.Today; 
        return Enumerable.Range( 1, 4 )
            .Select( n => now.AddDays( -n ) )
            .Where( d => d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday )
            .Take( 3 )
            .Select( d => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = d.ToString("o"), // "o" for the RoundTrip format
                Text = d.ToString("d")
            } );
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        this.ViewData["dates"] = GenerateLastThreeDates();
        return this.View( new IndexViewModel() );
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if( this.ModelState.IsValid )
        {
            DoSomething( viewModel.SelectedDate );

            return this.RedirectToAction( nameof(this.Index) );
        }
        else
        {
            this.ViewData["dates"] = GenerateLastThreeDates();
            return this.View( viewModel );
        }
    }
```

}

#### ViewModel.cs

```
public class IndexViewModel {

    [Required]
    public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }
}
```

#### View.cshtml

```
@{ IEnumerable<SelectListItem> dates = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)this.ViewData["dates"]; }

<p>Select a date: @Html.DropDownListFor( m = m.SelectedDate, dates )</p>
```

Comment: I see no reason to store this data in stringly typed ViewData instead of strongly typed view model. Of course, values will be empty when posted back, but you just fill them up every time.

Comment: @KasparsOzols It depends on your philosophy of ViewData vs ViewModel. In my own projects I actually have strong-typed ViewData classes (I subclass `WebViewPage<TViewModel>` with `MyViewPage<TViewData,TViewModel>`) to enable this scenario.

Comment: Thanks. Looking at the method GenerateLastThreeDates(), I want Yesterdays date to always be the first date in the dropdown. Do I need an orderby ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `GenerateLastThreeDates` method returns a collection of `MyDates` and each item in that collection has a `Dateseries` property to which you are setting the date time. So basically you need to select that property when you do the Select method call.

```
var myCollection = GenerateLastThreeDates()
                     .Select(i => new SelectListItem
                                      {
                                        Text = i.Dateseries.ToString(), 
                                        Value = i.Dateseries.ToString()
                                      });
```

`myCollection` is a collection of SelectListItem where the Text and Value property holds the testing version of the date value. You can use this collction to build the select element using `Html.DropDownListFor` or `Html.DropDownList` helper method.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just define extension method like this:

```
    public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItems<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, object> textSelector, Func<T, object> valueSelector, string emptyText = "- Choose-",
        string emptyValue = null)
    {
        var result = new List<SelectListItem>();

        if (collection != null)
        {
            var items = collection
                .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = textSelector(x)?.ToString(),
                    Value = valueSelector(x)?.ToString()
                })
                .ToList();
            result.AddRange(items);
        }

        if (emptyText != null)
        {
            result.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = emptyText, Value = emptyValue ?? string.Empty });
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Then:

1) Add possible values to the model as any `IEnumerable<T>`

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public List<Country> AllCountries { get; set; } = new List<Country>();
}
```

2) fill the possible values in the controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyModel
    {
        AllCountries = _repository.GetCountries();
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

3) use this extension method directly in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CountryId, Model.AllCountries.ToSelectListItems(x => x.CountryName, x => x.CountryId))
```